# Tennis Statistics By Sets and Games

Tags: tennis, statistics, atp, wta

I am trying to find a resource where I can find the results for historic tennis games, where the match statistics are broken down within each set. The ATP website gives a breakdown for the entire match e.g. [Wimbledon 2015 Final](http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/tournaments/wimbledon/540/2015/match-stats/D643/F324/live/MS001/match-stats), but I would like to know the same statistics broken down by set (or even by game if possible).

Comment: Discussion in the comments [here](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5626/in-tennis-how-much-is-the-servers-advantage-diminished-if-the-game-goes-to-de#comment13259_5632) seems (to some extent) related.

Comment: I will mention that for example [this website](http://www.flashscore.com/) has both [various stats](http://www.flashscore.com/match/d0k3Qj33/#match-statistics;0) and eve [point-by-point data](http://www.flashscore.com/match/d0k3Qj33/#point-by-point;1) for top level tennis tournaments from recent years. I suppose that it is possible to find several sites which provide similar data. But I do not know about a website which has data before year 2000. (In fact, the site I linked to has only stats after cca 2010.)

Comment: Similar questions posted at other websites: Quora: [Are there any tennis datasets available?](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-tennis-datasets-available)
Reddit: [Where to find old match statistics?](https://www.reddit.com/r/tennis/comments/3a69j6/where_to_find_old_match_statistics/)

Comment: Thanks @Martin, the [link](http://www.flashscore.com/) was just the thing I was looking for.

Comment: It's very strange that some questions are being voted down to be closed as off-topic as they contain resource requests, whereas others are protected by Community.
http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because requests for off-site resources are off topic on this site.

Comment: A discussion on meta related to gdrt's comment: [Double Standards in Questions Containing Resource Requests](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/753).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most detailed publicly available professional tennis match dataset I'm aware of can be found on a website called [tennisabstract](http://www.tennisabstract.com) run by [Jeff Sackmann](http://www.heavytopspin.com). For the information you are interested in I recommend checking out the [detailed match reports](http://www.tennisabstract.com/charting/meta.html), which are compiled as part of the [match charting project](http://www.sloansportsconference.com/?p=15758). The "point-by-point" description of a match tells you everything that occurred during each point (including the kind and placement of each shot the players hit).

While they don't have reports on *every* recent match, they do have 507 mens matches and 546 women's matches; some charted matches date back as far as the 1980's, but the records are heavily weighted toward matches after 2010.

The charted matches can be found in a form more amenable to comprehensive analysis on [Sackmann's GitHub page](https://github.com/JeffSackmann).